# jquery repeatly attributes - google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var markers = [

            {

                "lat": '51.508742',
                "lng": '-0.12085'

            }

];
        window.onload = function () {

            var mapOptions = {

                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                fullscreenControl: true,
                styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#6195a0"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#e6f3d6"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f4d2c5"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"color":"#4e4e4e"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f4f4f4"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#787878"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#eaf6f8"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eaf6f8"}]}]

            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

}

$("#tab_id_1 li").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var data_lat1 = $(this).attr('data-lat-1');
    var data_lng1 = $(this).attr('data-lng-1');
    var data_lat2 = $(this).attr('data-lat-2');
    var data_lng2 = $(this).attr('data-lng-2');
    map(data_lat1,data_lng1,data_lat2,data_lng2);

});

function map(data_lat1,data_lng1,data_lat2,data_lng2){

         $("#tab_id_1 li").on("click",function(){

            var markers = [

            {

                "lat": ''+ data_lat1 +'',
                "lng": ''+ data_lng1 +''

            }
        ,
            {

                "lat": ''+ data_lat2 +'',
                "lng": ''+ data_lng2 +''

            }
];
 console.log(markers);
            var mapOptions = {

                zoom: 7,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                fullscreenControl: true,
                styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#6195a0"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#e6f3d6"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f4d2c5"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"color":"#4e4e4e"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f4f4f4"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#787878"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#eaf6f8"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eaf6f8"}]}]

            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var lat_lng = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title,
                    icon: "marker-icon.png"
                });
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

            //***********ROUTING****************//

            //Intialize the Path Array
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

            //Intialize the Direction Service
            var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#f09c00', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 5 });

            //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
            for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                    var src = lat_lng[i];
                    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                    path.push(src);
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    service.route({
                        origin: src,
                        destination: des,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    }, function (result, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                                path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
    });
```

Help please! when the first time is pushed, nothing happens, then when you press again on one of the "li" the coordinates are sent with 1 array, the third time when the push is sent 2 arrays, the fourth time is sent 3 arrays, the fifth time is sent 4 arrays, how can I solve the problem, when I'm pushing to send only 1 array, sorry for my bad english.

```
<ul id="tab_id_1" class="uk-nestable" data-uk-nestable="{group:'my-group', maxDepth:1}">


        <li data-lat-1="51.5501741" data-lng-1="-0.003371000000015556" data-lat-2="-33.88081" data-lng-2="-33.88081"  class="uk-nestable-item">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_1[]" value="9">
        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
        <div>
        <div class="table dd_table">

        <div>Sat30</div>
        <div>Nr.Q767</div>
        <div>DELIVERY</div>
        <div>754876</div>
        <div><a href="....." title="View JOB"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></div>


        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li data-lat-1="48.57340529999999" data-lng-1="7.752111300000024" data-lat-2="51.5111922" data-lng-2="51.5111922"  class="uk-nestable-item">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_1[]" value="7">
        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
        <div>
        <div class="table dd_table">

        <div>Sat30</div>
        <div>Nr.W996</div>
        <div>DELIVERY</div>
        <div>5365-64</div>
        <div><a href="....." title="View JOB"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></div>


        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li data-lat-1="48.57340529999999" data-lng-1="7.752111300000024" data-lat-2="52.19173" data-lng-2="52.19173"  class="uk-nestable-item">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_1[]" value="11">
        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
        <div>
        <div class="table dd_table">

        <div>Sat30</div>
        <div>Nr.J765</div>
        <div>PICK-UP/DELIVERY</div>
        <div>MD-2038/3811-558</div>
        <div><a href="......" title="View JOB"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></div>


        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `map()` doing, and what shouldn't it be doing (hint: first line)?

Comment: you dont need the second click event $("#tab_id_1 li").on("click",function(){
 inside the map function

Comment: Srikant Sahu, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the

```
$("#tab_id_1 li").on("click",function(){
```

re declaration inside the map function..
That should solve your problem.